# Wordpress site speed issue

Tags: wordpress, elementor, sitespeed

I have a WordPress website using Elementor. Hosting it using Managed WordPress by GoDaddy. I need to improve the site speed but facing a few issues:

1. Elementor plugin makes the site slow. But currently I do not plan to change the plugin as I am using the pro version as well. (Tested it by deactivating Elementor and Elementor Pro)
2. GoDaddy does not allow me to install certain cache plugins.
3. Even if I use a plugin like Hummingbird (which is allowed by GoDaddy), our team continues make changes in existing pages. Hence changes made by the team, do not get reflected on existing pages. Hence cannot use cache plugins to improve site speed.
4. Tools such as PageSpeedInsights and Gtmetrix suggest deferring of javascripts. I have added the code in my child theme. But it continues to throw the same issue. Have tried multiple versions of the code.

Current code:

```
function defer_parsing_of_js( $url ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return $url;
    if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
    if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
    return str_replace( ' src', ' defer src', $url );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 10 );
```

Request you to suggest solutions/alternatives in improving the site speed on desktops as well as hand-held devices.

Comment: Do you use a cache plugin ?

Comment: @ZecKa Currently I had deactivated the cache plugin.

Comment: Find better hosting.

Comment: There are many issue that cause your WP site slowly, maybe come from your hosting server or your internal factors. Factors like plugins, etc can cause your wordpress become slowly, you can read this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/oh-god-my-wordpress-site-load-like-a-snail-am-i-wrong-to-choose-my-hosting-provider/ for further info.

Comment: @Mark Spencer Thanks. Unable to resolve using the solutions mentioned in the link. Also the Hyper cache plugin mentioned in the link should not be used as it is a very old plugin.

Comment: @user3367662 You can use W3 Total Cache or Super Cache as your plugins.

Comment: @MarkSpencer : These plugins are not allowed by GoDaddy managed Wordpress. The message displayed is : This plugin is not allowed on our system due to performance, security, or compatibility concerns.

Comment: Hah? It should be no problem. That's very common plugins. It is weird if you don't have permission to install this plugin. FYI, I just use shared hosting on Asphostportal, and no issue installing this plugins.

Answer (score -1):

try litespeed cache plugin,

https://wordpress.org/plugins/litespeed-cache/

and set option to purge all cache when editing pages or post,
it will auto clear cache and it provides functionality like, deferring of javascripts, css and js minify and combine, lazy loading etc..

Comment: Thanks @Tretanz Infotech. I tried using the litespeed cache plugin but the site breaks on using it.